# Firebase phone auth react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to implement *firebase* phone authentication in *react js* without using the *firebase UI*.
How do I do it?

code

```js
requestVerificationCode = () => {
    const { phoneNumber } = this.state;
    const appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
      "recaptcha-container"
    );
    if (phoneNumber < 10) {
      this.setState({ error: true });
    } else {
      this.setState({ message: "Sending code ..." });

      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
        .then(confirmResult =>
          this.setState({ confirmResult, verifying: true })
        )
        .catch(error =>
          this.setState({
            message: `Sign In With Phone Number Error: ${error.message}`
          })
        );
    }
  };
```

error

---

auth.esm.js:282
Uncaught K {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "reCAPTCHA container is either not found or already contains inner elements!"}

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: You need to have an element with the ID of `recaptcha-container` in your html

Comment: Still not working @TheUnreal

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I managed to get the above working by including e.preventDefault().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The important part is to wait for `componentDidMount()` or `mounted()` in Vue JS so that the dom element containing `"recaptcha-container"` is mounted.

HTML

```
<input id="recaptcha-container" type="button" onClick="this.onClick" />
```

JS

```
componentDidMount () {
    window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container",
    {
       size:"invisible"
        // other options
    });
}

onClick() {
    const phoneNumber = this.phone;
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
    firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then(confirmResult => {
      // success
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // error
    });
}
```

If you re-direct the user away from your component where `id="recaptcha-container"` lives, then recaptcha will work fine but throw a style related error in the console, but that's because it's wants a permanent place on the page.

Answer (score 0):

In React JS you will need to put this in index.html in public folder.

```
<input id="recaptcha-container" type="button" onClick="this.onClick" />
```

Alternatively, you can also create the html on dom.

```
  const tag = document.createElement("input");
  tag.id = "recaptcha-container"; // need to be same id as your firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier below
  tag.type="button" 
  tag.onClick="this.onClick"
  document.body.appendChild(tag);
```

then

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container", {
    size: "invisible",
    callback: (response) => {
      // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
      console.log("Submitted  window.recaptchaVerifier: ", response);

    },
    "expired-callback": (e) => {
      console.log("Expired Callback: ", e);
      // Response expired. Ask user to solve reCAPTCHA again.
      // ...
    },
  });
```